What's the best way to fill the missing values of a column in Azure Data Explorer when creating materialised views on the raw data table?
We're trying to create a transformed and aggregated view of our raw sensoric data in ADX using a materialised view. one of the requirements is to forward fill the values as our sensors don't emit a value at the same rate and when we're aggregating the data into 10 minute bins, some of the sensors have missing values.
I tried using the scan operator to forward fill my column when creating the materialised view but scan needs the table to be seriliased or sorted and materialised views don't like that based on this.
When trying to create the materialised view with the scan operator inside the query, we get the following error:
"State": Failed,
"Status": Cannot create materialized view : Materialized view query cannot include partition operator or operators that require serialization (e.g., order by, sort by, serialize, top.,

I also tried to create a function to forward fill the data when querying the materialised view but that makes the performance a lot worse as it performs the forward filling whenever we're using the function to query the data.
How do you suggest to fill the missing 10 minute bins in our view?
Thanks

As the error message suggests, you cannot use fill forward in a materialized view. If this cannot be done during query time, then the only option is to create the periodic aggregations using your own custom orchestration and not using materialized views. You can schedule the process using orchestration tools (see data integrations documentation) and periodically ingest the aggregations (after fill forward) using ingest from query commands.

Thank you for the suggestion, I almost achieved the same you mentioned using update policies on my source table. I will update my post once I make sure the logic is working. I used your idea and also some help from https://veldify.com/2023/11/28/how-to-deal-with-change-data-capture-in-azure-data-explorer-part-2/
